# How to save video overlay iphone xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have created an overlay to an MPMoviePlayerController using the following code, which essentially adds a subtitle in my iphone xcode project:

```
[_mpMoviePlayerController.view addSubview:lblOverlayView];
```

I want to now be able to save the video (and eventually facebook, but I don't NEED help with that, just the saving would be fine) with the subtitles. It is playing a preloaded video, and the dynamic part is the subtitle, which is whatever text the user enters (which becomes the value of lblOverlayView. If you have any other ways of adding text that can very over the top of a preexxisting/preloaded video and then saving/emailing/facebooking it, that would also be great! Just some way of doing it!!

Any help I can get will be hugely appreciated.